# Randomly choose a game executable from a folder

Tags: c#, performance, file-system, xaml

I've written a Universal Windows Application which allows you to select a folder and shows the icon and name of a random executable from anywhere in that folder. The intent is to be a Game Roulette, where if you install all your games in a certain folder, it will tell you what game to play.

**MainPage.xaml:**

```
<Page
    x:Class="GameRoulette.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:GameRoulette"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:viewmodels="using:GameRoulette" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" Width="400" Height="400">
    <Grid x:Name="prgrGettingGames" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Button x:Name="btnSelectGames" Content="Click here to select your games"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="110,50,0,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="240"
                Click="SelectGames_Click"/>

        <Button x:Name="btnChooseGame" Content="{Binding ChooseGameText, Mode=OneWay}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="110,150,0,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="240" Height="40"
                Click="ChooseGame_Click" IsEnabled="{Binding ChooseGameEnabled, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <ProgressRing HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="200,100,0,0" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="1.05,1.983"
                      Height="45" Width="45" IsActive="True" Visibility="{Binding ProgressRingVisibility, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <Image x:Name="imgFileIcon" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Height="64" Margin="110,224,0,0"
               VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="64" Source="{Binding FileThumbnail, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="lblFileName" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Margin="200,224,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   Text="{Binding Filename, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>   
    </Grid>  
</Page>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
using Windows.Storage.Pickers;
using Windows.Storage;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace GameRoulette
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private IEnumerable<StorageFile> Files;
        public MainPageViewModel PageViewModel { get; set; }
        int i;
        int fileCount;
        int exeFileCount;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PageViewModel = new MainPageViewModel();
            i = 0;
            DataContext = PageViewModel;
        }
        private async void SelectGames_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            FolderPicker folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
            folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".exe");
            PageViewModel.ProgressRingVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
            StorageFolder selectedFolder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
            PageViewModel.ChooseGameText = "retrieving files";
            IEnumerable<StorageFile> retrievedFiles = await selectedFolder.GetFilesAsync(Windows.Storage.Search.CommonFileQuery.OrderByName);
            fileCount = retrievedFiles.Count();
            Files = retrievedFiles.Where(file => ValidateFile(file)).ToList();
            if (!Files.Any())
            {
                PageViewModel.Filename = "No executables found.";
                return;
            }
            exeFileCount = Files.Count();
            PageViewModel.ProgressRingVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            PageViewModel.ChooseGameText = string.Format("{0} games found. Click here to choose your game.", exeFileCount);
            PageViewModel.ChooseGameEnabled = true;

        }

        private bool ValidateFile(StorageFile file)
        {
            string[] blacklist = { "uninst", "system", "redist" };
            PageViewModel.ChooseGameText = string.Format("{0} of {1} files checked.", i, fileCount);
            i++;
            if (file.FileType != ".exe")
            {
                return false;
            }
            foreach(string item in blacklist)
            {
                if (file.Name.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(item))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        private async void ChooseGame_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Files.Any())
            {
                return;
            }
            Random generator = new Random();
            int index = generator.Next(0, exeFileCount - 1);
            StorageFile chosenGame = Files.ToList().ElementAt(index);
            Windows.Storage.FileProperties.StorageItemThumbnail thumbnail = await chosenGame.GetScaledImageAsThumbnailAsync(Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailMode.SingleItem, 64);
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
            image.SetSource(thumbnail);
            PageViewModel.FileThumbnail = image;
            PageViewModel.Filename = chosenGame.DisplayName;

        }
    }

    public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
    {
        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            fileThumbnail = new BitmapImage();
            progressRingVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            chooseGameEnabled = false;
            filename = "no games loaded";
            chooseGameText = "Please choose a game first";
        }


        private ImageSource fileThumbnail;
        private Visibility progressRingVisibility;
        private bool chooseGameEnabled;
        private string filename;
        private string chooseGameText;


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;


        public void OnPropertyChanging(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanging != null)
                PropertyChanging.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangingEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
            }
        }

        public string ChooseGameText
        {
            get { return chooseGameText; }
            set
            {
                OnPropertyChanging("ChooseGameText");
                chooseGameText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ChooseGameText");
            }
        }

        public ImageSource FileThumbnail
        {
            get { return fileThumbnail; }
            set
            {
                OnPropertyChanging("FileThumbnail");
                fileThumbnail = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FileThumbnail");

            }
        }
        public Visibility ProgressRingVisibility
        {
            get
            {
                return progressRingVisibility;
            }
            set
            {
                OnPropertyChanging("ProgressRingVisibility");
                progressRingVisibility = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ProgressRingVisibility");
            }
        }
        public bool ChooseGameEnabled
        {
            get { return chooseGameEnabled; }
            set
            {
                OnPropertyChanging("ChooseGameEnabled");
                chooseGameEnabled = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ChooseGameEnabled");
            }
        }
        public string Filename
        {
            get { return filename; }
            set
            {
                OnPropertyChanging("Filename");
                filename = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Filename");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code does what it should do. I have knowledge of 1 major and 2 minor bugs, but none of them are really breaking bugs:

1. MAJOR: from what I can tell, it does not handle symbolic links well. I have several games symbolically linked from another drive, but they're not found.
2. MINOR: `PageViewModel.ChooseGameText` isn't updated during the Where() clause, which means that doesn't show a progress.
3. MINOR: my blacklist is incomplete, but that's just a matter of adding the right items.

I have also noticed that it's quite slow compared to other similar software. For example, WinDirStat takes under 2 minutes to check my entire C: drive. This program isn't finished with that after 20 minutes AND makes the Runtime Broker use 4 GB of memory, which causes system warning for out of memory.

Comment: Please stop putting all the logic in the code behind. WPF was designed to use an MVVM architecture. Learn about commands and stop this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things noticed by just looking over the code in no particular order:

1. The `blacklist` should be a static readonly class member - there is no need to create the array on every call to `ValidateFile`.
2. The variable `i` should not be a class member. `Where` has an overload which passes the current index along so you should use that instead. Also `fileCount` should not be a class member since it's only used to track progress. The current index and total count should be passed in as parameters to the `ValidateFile` method rather than being class state.
3. `Files` gets set as `ToList()` yet you have another `ToList()` call on it in the `ChooseGame_Click` method. This will create another copy of the whole list and wastes time and memory for no reason at all. Just have the type as `IList` instead of `IEnumerable`. In that case `exeFileCount` becomes obsolete.
4. In `ValidateFile` the filename gets converted to lower case for every entry in the blacklist - again waste of memory and time. Just store the lowered file name in a local variable and compare against it. Also some LINQ could be employed to make this a bit more succinct.
5. The canonical way to invoke an event handler was this:

   ```
   var handler = MyEventHandler;
   if (handler != null)
   {
       handler(this, new MyEventArgs());
   }
   ```

   This avoids a potential race where the last handler unsubscribes after checking against null but before actually executing the handler.

   In C# 6.0 you can simply use the [Null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx):

   ```
   MyEventHandler?.Invoke(this, new MyEventArgs())
   ```

---

A simple rewrite of `MainPage` would look like this:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private IList<StorageFile> Files;
    public MainPageViewModel PageViewModel { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PageViewModel = new MainPageViewModel();
        DataContext = PageViewModel;
    }
    private async void SelectGames_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FolderPicker folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
        folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".exe");
        PageViewModel.ProgressRingVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        StorageFolder selectedFolder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
        PageViewModel.ChooseGameText = "retrieving files";

        var retrievedFiles = await selectedFolder.GetFilesAsync(Windows.Storage.Search.CommonFileQuery.OrderByName);
        var fileCount = retrievedFiles.Count;

        Files = retrievedFiles.Where((file, index) => ValidateFile(file, index, fileCount)).ToList();
        if (!Files.Any())
        {
            PageViewModel.Filename = "No executables found.";
            return;
        }

        PageViewModel.ProgressRingVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        PageViewModel.ChooseGameText = string.Format("{0} games found. Click here to choose your game.", exeFileCount);
        PageViewModel.ChooseGameEnabled = true;
    }

    static readonly string[] blacklist = { "uninst", "system", "redist" };

    private bool ValidateFile(StorageFile file, int currentIndex, int totalNumberOfFiles)
    {
        PageViewModel.ChooseGameText = string.Format("{0} of {1} files checked.", currentIndex, totalNumberOfFiles);
        if (file.FileType != ".exe")
        {
            return false;
        }
        var lowerCaseFilename = file.Name.ToLowerInvariant();
        return blacklist.Any(e => lowerCaseFilename.Contains(e));
    }

    private async void ChooseGame_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Files.Any())
        {
            return;
        }
        Random generator = new Random();
        int index = generator.Next(0, Files.Count - 1);
        StorageFile chosenGame = Files[index];
        Windows.Storage.FileProperties.StorageItemThumbnail thumbnail = await chosenGame.GetScaledImageAsThumbnailAsync(Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailMode.SingleItem, 64);
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.SetSource(thumbnail);
        PageViewModel.FileThumbnail = image;
        PageViewModel.Filename = chosenGame.DisplayName;
    }
}
```

This could probably still be improved but it's somewhat cleaner now.