# Randomly choose a game executable from a folder 2.0

Tags: c#, performance, file-system, mvvm, xaml

After asking [Randomly choose a game executable from a folder](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/118627/randomly-choose-a-game-executable-from-a-folder), I applied the recommended changes. I also redesigned the program to make use of the MVVM (Model-View-Viewmodel) paradigm, using Prism 6.0. This was such a large change that I bumped the version number to 2.0.

The project can be found at https://github.com/nzall/GameRoulette. I will copy the relevant files below:

MainPage.xaml (.cs is basically empty and is not worth sharing):

```
<Page
    x:Class="GameRoulette.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:GameRoulette"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:grv="using:GameRoulette.Views"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Width="400" Height="400">
    <Grid>
        <grv:GameRouletteView></grv:GameRouletteView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

GameRouletteView.xaml (again, associated .cs file is basically empty, so no point sharing):

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="GameRoulette.Views.GameRouletteView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:GameRoulette.Views"  
    xmlns:prism="using:Prism.Windows.Mvvm" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
    <Grid Background="White">
        <Button x:Name="btnSelectGames" Content="Click here to select your games"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="110,50,0,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="240"
                Command="{Binding SelectCommand}"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnChooseGame" Content="{Binding ChooseGameText}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="110,150,0,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="240" Height="40"
                Command="{Binding ChooseCommand}"
                IsEnabled="{Binding ChooseGameEnabled}"/>
        <ProgressRing HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="200,100,0,0" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="1.05,1.983"
                      Height="45" Width="45" IsActive="True" Visibility="{Binding ProgressRingVisibility}"/>
        <Image x:Name="imgFileIcon" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Source="{Binding FileThumbnail}"
               Height="64" Margin="110,224,0,0"
               VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="64" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="lblFileName" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Margin="179,224,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   Text="{Binding Filename}"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="171" Height="64"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

GameRouletteViewModel.cs

```
using Prism.Mvvm;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.Pickers;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
using GameRoulette.Models;
using Prism.Commands;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GameRoulette.ViewModels
{
    public class GameRouletteViewModel : BindableBase
    {

        private ImageSource fileThumbnail;
        private Visibility progressRingVisibility;
        private bool chooseGameEnabled;
        private string filename;
        private string chooseGameText;
        private GameRouletteModel Model;
        public DelegateCommand SelectCommand { get; private set; }
        public DelegateCommand ChooseCommand { get; private set; }

        public GameRouletteViewModel()
        {
            progressRingVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            chooseGameEnabled = false;
            ChooseGameText = "First select a folder";
            filename = "";
            FileThumbnail = new BitmapImage();
            Model = new GameRouletteModel();
            SelectCommand = DelegateCommand.FromAsyncHandler(SelectFolderAsync);
            ChooseCommand = DelegateCommand.FromAsyncHandler(OnChooseGameClick);
        }

        public async Task SelectFolderAsync()
        {

            FolderPicker folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
            folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".exe");
            ProgressRingVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
            StorageFolder selectedFolder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();

            ChooseGameText = "retrieving files";

            int fileCount = await Model.SelectGameExecutables(selectedFolder);


            ProgressRingVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            ChooseGameText = string.Format("{0} games found. Click here to choose your game.", fileCount);
            ChooseGameEnabled = true;
        }



        public async Task OnChooseGameClick()
        {

            Tuple<BitmapImage, string> fileProperties = await Model.ChooseGame();
            FileThumbnail = fileProperties.Item1;
            Filename = fileProperties.Item2;

        }


        public string ChooseGameText
        {
            get { return chooseGameText; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref chooseGameText, value);
            }
        }

        public ImageSource FileThumbnail
        {
            get { return fileThumbnail; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref fileThumbnail, value);
                

            }
        }
        public Visibility ProgressRingVisibility
        {
            get
            {
                return progressRingVisibility;
            }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref progressRingVisibility, value);
                
            }
        }
        public bool ChooseGameEnabled
        {
            get { return chooseGameEnabled; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref chooseGameEnabled, value);
                
            }
        }
        public string Filename
        {
            get { return filename; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref filename, value);
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

GameRouletteModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;

namespace GameRoulette.Models
{
    class GameRouletteModel
    {

        string[] blacklist = { "uninst", "system", "redist", "framework", "physx", "builder", "processor", "helper" };
        IList<StorageFile> Files;


        public async Task<int> SelectGameExecutables(StorageFolder folder)
        {
            IEnumerable<StorageFile> retrievedFiles = await folder.GetFilesAsync(Windows.Storage.Search.CommonFileQuery.OrderByName);
            var fileCount = retrievedFiles.Count();

            Files = retrievedFiles.Where((file, index) => ValidateFile(file, index, fileCount)).ToList();

            return Files.Count;
        }

        private bool ValidateFile(StorageFile file, int index, int fileCount)
        {
            if (file.FileType != ".exe")
            {
                return false;
            }
            var lowerCaseFileName = file.Name.ToLowerInvariant();
            return !blacklist.Any(e => lowerCaseFileName.Contains(e));
        }

        internal async Task<Tuple<BitmapImage, string>> ChooseGame()
        {
            if (!Files.Any())
            {
                return null;
            }
            Random generator = new Random();
            int index = generator.Next(0, Files.Count - 1);
            StorageFile chosenGame = Files[index];
            Windows.Storage.FileProperties.StorageItemThumbnail thumbnail = await chosenGame.GetScaledImageAsThumbnailAsync(Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailMode.SingleItem, 64);
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
            image.SetSource(thumbnail);
            return new Tuple<BitmapImage, string> (image, chosenGame.DisplayName);
        }
    }
}
```

2 of the 3 bugs from before are still present. I removed one of the bugs since it doesn't really

> MAJOR: from what I can tell, it does not handle symbolic links well. I have several games symbolically linked from another drive, but they're not found.
>
> MINOR: my blacklist is incomplete, but that's just a matter of adding the right items.
>
> I have also noticed that it's quite slow compared to other similar software. For example, WinDirStat takes under 2 minutes to check my entire C: drive. This program isn't finished with that after 20 minutes AND makes the Runtime Broker use 4 GB of memory, which causes system warning for out of memory.

The first Major bug might be a limitation of GetFilesAsync. The Minor bug is just a matter of testing until a proper blacklist has been found.

the performance issues, however, are quite concerning. I am not sure if they are fixable though.

Special feedback I'm looking for on top of normal refactoring:

1. Have I implemented MVVM using Prism properly?
2. Are the performance issues solvable?
3. Is the major bug solvable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> <grv:GameRouletteView></grv:GameRouletteView>
> ```

The tag should be self-closing if there's nothing in it:

```
<grv:GameRouletteView />
```

You're using `x:Name` attributes, but the identifiers aren't used anywhere and can be discarded: that's a very often very good sign you're doing something right, when your XAML doesn't need *named controls*.

What I don't like though, is all these explicit margins: I don't know what your UI looks like, but it seems you could use better layouts; explicit margins everywhere are a sign that you're dragging-and-dropping your controls into the designer - that *works*, but you'll have a much better UI if you let WPF handle the layout; you're literally dumping your controls into that `Grid` with explicit positioning, as if drawing on a canvas.

You could start by defining rows and columns for your grid:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" /> <!-- todo -->
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

And then use layout panels, for example `StackPanel`, wisely and as needed:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
    <!-- controls -->
</StackPanel>
```

Seeing a textbox's `Width=171` in the markup, begs the question: why isn't it 170? With a structured layout, you get rid of arbitrary margins like `179,224,0,0`, and let the controls take the space they're allowed to take - you can constrain grid rows/columns' `MinHeight` and/or `MaxWidth` to keep things under control, and the result is a view that adapts much better to resizing.

In other words, using explicit margins everywhere is the [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) way of doing layout.

---

Code-wise, I don't like seeing a `Tuple<T1,T2>` in any API, even if it's `internal`. What you're returning from that `ChooseGame` method could have its own name:

```
internal class GameInfo
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage Thumbnail { get; set; }
}
```

And then the signature and call sites become much more readable:

```
internal async Task<GameInfo> ChooseGame()
```

And then instead of this:

> ```
> Tuple<BitmapImage, string> fileProperties = await Model.ChooseGame();
> FileThumbnail = fileProperties.Item1;
> Filename = fileProperties.Item2;
> ```

You could have that:

```
var info = await Model.ChooseGame();
FileThumbnail = info.Thumbnail;
Filename = info.FileName;
```

This is a problem:

```
Random generator = new Random();
```

It should be an instance-level field, not a new instance every time it's called.

Also, `blacklist` could be a `private readonly IReadOnlyList<string>` instead of a simple array.

---

`Visibility` should be `bool IsVisible`:

> ```
> public Visibility ProgressRingVisibility
> {
>     get
>     {
>         return progressRingVisibility;
>     }
>     set
>     {
>         SetProperty(ref progressRingVisibility, value);
>
>     }
> }
> ```

I'm not sure why you're calling `SetProperty` here, why can't you just assign the value and `OnPropertyChanged`? Or is that some magic going on in `BindableBase`? I'm not sure I like that it needs that `ref` parameter, and `SetProperty` makes it look like you're assigning a `DependencyProperty`, which shouldn't be the case here.

The ViewModel exposing a `bool Visibility` will obviously break your binding:

> ```
> Visibility="{Binding ProgressRingVisibility}"
> ```

The trick is to add a `<UserControl.Resources>` section where you give an `x:Key` to a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`, like this:

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibility"/>`
```

And then you update the binding with the converter:

```
Visibility="{Binding ProgressRingVisibility, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"
```

The concept of `Visibility` shouldn't be leaking into your ViewModel; it's really a presentation thing. Hence I'd probably expose it as some `bool IsBusy` or whatever fits the bill here.

Comment: `BindableBase` is a class from `Prism`, a Microsoft-generated NuGet package that abstracts away all that OnPropertyChanged and handler boilerplate code for WPF binding. Also, it's a UWP project, and from what I've developed since the question, I seem to remember not coming across the `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` class.

Comment: At any rate, I've had my brother go over my MVVM implementation and apparently, the way I implemented it is not even close to true MVVM. what I currently have is basically the classic 3 layers model. I'm going to rewrite the entire project a 3rd time for TRUE MVVM implementation. For example, Model would be a file, and View Model would be the class that selects the file.

Comment: The converter is merely an implementation of `IValueConverter` - make your own if it's not available! Also, design patterns are a mean of communication, not a coding standard. What matters is whether your code is robust, readable, maintainable and flexible, not whether it adheres to such or such blog's definition of what MVVM should be.